# Convert Y to 12% and N to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The result of the discount table is Y,N . if Y = 12% if N = 0

```
select
    Product_id, basic_price, cost, discount
from prcdpr
where strdate = '210319'
```

Also I want to add a formula above `(Price+cost)/discount`.

My query result

```
Product_id          | basic_price   | cost         | Discount
------------------------------------------------------------
998723              |  24           |   18         | Y
992351              |  32           |   25         | N
```

My expected result with `(price+cost)/discount`

```
Product_id          | basic_price        | cost         | Discount    | Price
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
998723              | 24                 |   18         | 12%         | 37.5
992351              | 32                 |   25         | 0           | 57
```

Comment: So whats stopping you from adding your formula to your query?

Comment: Discount table is Y and N, i want to convert them first to 12% and 0. but i dont know how.

Comment: Have you tried using `case`? You could at least add your formula to your query and then your question becomes how to apply the discount conditionally. Having it hardcoded as 12% is probably a bad choice also... you're sure to be asked to change it at a later date. Best to store discounts in their own table with a valid date range.

Comment: I don't get how you come up with 37.5 in the example given the formula you have.

Comment: @Stidgeon, you're correct that the math in the example doesn't quite add up ...

Comment: i do like this (24+18)/1.12.

Comment: okay - thanks - i see what you did. glad you got the answer you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not completely familiar with T-SQL, you are likely after a CASE expression in your query to derive the Discount % value

Eg.

```
select
    Product_id, basic_price, cost, --discount,
    CASE WHEN discount = 'Y' THEN 12.000
    ELSE 0.000
    END AS [Discount], 
    (
        (basic_price + cost) * 
        (1.000 - (
            (CASE WHEN discount = 'Y' THEN 12.000
             ELSE 0.000
             END)/100.000))
    ) AS [Price]
from prcdpr
where strdate = '210319'
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to calculate this sort of thing once using `cross apply` rather than having to repeat the calculation and risk it not being identical.

I don't know if you really needed a percentage sign after your discount, but thats what I've done.

```
declare @PrcDpr table (Product_Id int, Basic_Price money, Cost money, Discount char(1), StrDate varchar(6));

insert into @PrcDpr (Product_Id, Basic_Price, Cost, Discount, StrDate)
values
(998723, 24, 18, 'Y', '210319'),
(992351, 32, 25, 'N', '210319');

select
    Product_id, basic_price, cost
    , convert(varchar(32),convert(int, X.DiscountRate)) + '%' Discount
    , convert(decimal(9,2),(basic_price + cost) * (1.00 - (X.DiscountRate/100.00))) Price
from @PrcDpr
cross apply (values (case when discount = 'Y' then 12.00 else 0.00 end)) X (DiscountRate)
where strdate = '210319';
```

Returns:

| Product_Id | Basic_Price | Cost | Discount | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 998723 | 24.00 | 18.00 | 12% | 36.96 |
| 992351 | 32.00 | 25.00 | 0% | 57.00 |

Note 1: The results don't match yours - I assume you made a mistake.

Note 2: I highly recommend storing your dates **properly** using the `date` datatype. Using strings is the cause of much pain for many people.

Note 3: If you setup your future questions with DDL+DML for your sample data (as shown here) it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Dale, some good advice, for sure - although, it's probably also fair to say that if someone is not up to using CASE in their T-SQL yet, then table variables and cross applys are quite a step.  Also, regarding Note 2, we don't know the full structure of the OPs table, but '210319' is a valid string for date comparison (which SQL will likely - in most cases, weird collations aside - treat as March 19, 2021).  Me, personally, I would tend to use '2021-03-19', but each to their own, of course

Comment: @Craig Hmmm... if you use a relational database at all one assumes you are familiar with tables, so table variables aren't much of a step. And I wasn't referring to the date format, I was referring to the storage type. It only takes one date to be inserted as an incorrect string to stuff you up for years to come. And SO is designed as a repository for the future... so answers should not be aimed at the perceived ability of the OP. Answers should be the best solution to a given problem.